# What is the correct design for signals in a UML class diagram?

Tags: class, asynchronous, signals, uml, class-diagram

This is something that shouldn't be hard to find, but I searched for hours and couldn't find a definitive answer.

Following problem:

We have two classes. An active class "sensor" and a "device".

When the sensor detects something, it should inform the device about it. All of this must be defined in a class diagram.

My idea was that the sensor sends out a signal, which is then received by the device. Easy, right? I couldn't find the definitive correct way to model this!

First of all, how does a class sends a signal in a class diagram? I thought about an directed association from sensor to signal with the stereotype "send". Is that the right way to model it?

And how to show that the device received exactly that message? I know there is an compartment for receiving signals, but that can be overlooked easily. Is it allowed to create a direct (graphical) association between signal and receiver?

Comment: You're mixing static and dynamic design. CDs are static design. Signals dynamic. Will answer this evening unless someone else chips in.

Answer (score 2):

As you hopefully know by now, UML diagrams are in general grouped in two main categories: static and dynamic. They respectively represent, as the names suggest the information about the elements such as data structures, system components and so on (static) and interactions and system behaviours, functionalities and interactions.

Class diagram is one of the static diagrams so it does not offer you a straightforward way of showing the signal exchange specifically between two (or more) classes. You may model a fact that a specific class send a signal as well as that receiving a signal triggers behaviour of a class, but it does not indicate the direct connection between the classes. For that you will have to refer to dynamic diagrams and signal exchange can be depicted e.g. on activity diagram, sequence diagram and communication diagram.

In the class diagram the signal itself is depicted as a classifier, i.e. a rectangle. It has to have a stereotype `<<signal>>`

[image]

The reception can be depicted in the ... section of the classifier (especially class) in a form of Reception with the name matching the Signal name preceeded with a `<<signal>>` stereotype:

[image]

I did not find in specification any specific notation (within Class diagram) to indicate that a particular Class can send a signal. You can always use a Dependency (i.e. a dashed arrow with an open head) - as the weakest kind of a relationship. Using a stereotype `<<send>>` on that Dependency wouldn't do harm either.

I would discourage depicting the relation to the Signal as an Association as it would suggest the Signal being a Feature (efectively a Property) of that Class - and that is not true.

Comment: Actually it's a keyword (p. 168 of UML 2.5). But never mind ;-)

Comment: Thanks. But I wonder, how are asynchronous classes usually depicted in a class diagram? I searched and searched, but there were surprisingly little viable results. Are there actual examples "in the real world" of what you showed? (usage of a <<send>> stereotype, and a dependency?)

Comment: @SomeUserNameForThisWebsite classes are. it asynchronous. Asynchronousicity is something about the behaviors (“dynamics”), not about the structure. You may be onterested in sequence diagrams to show asynchronous exchanges and message exchanges

Comment: @qwerty_so oh, you're right. I'll correct it. It is always confusing when there is a stereotype-like indicator used that actually is a keyword.

Comment: @SomeUserNameForThisWebsite like Christophe already wrote, the fact of the call being synchronous or asynchronous is not the static part of the model but dynamic and should be depicted on respective diagrams. As I already wrote in the answer, the primary diagrams for that are activity diagram, sequence diagram and communication diagram. A frequent newbie approach is to try to represent both structure and behaviour in a single diagram. That is not how UML works.

Comment: Is the dependency-method also "allowed" with the signal and the receiver? To better show that the receiver receives exactly that signal? Despite having a compartment for that?

Comment: Yes. According to the UML specification, Dependency is the "weakest" kind of relationship. It shows that one of the entities has to know something about the other (the on on which it depends). In order to receive a Signal you definitely need to know about it, so you definitely have a Dependency here and you can put it on a diagram if you find it clearer. I often have similar approach when I use some data structure other than Clas (enums mostly) - I use it as the attribute type and create a Dependency to easily find the respecctive data type on the diagram (as well as for traceability purposes)